# Action Cable Chat App works on local but not on deploy to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, actioncable

Just what the title says.  Have finished the Learn Enough Action Cable tutorial and the app works great on the local server.  When I deploy to heroku, however, it falls apart.  Have to refresh the page for messages to show up.  @notifications do not work at all.

Comment: Are there any errors shown in the heroku logs?

Comment: No errors in the logs.